# Sharepoint Web Services Java - No data

Tags: java, sharepoint, service, web

I have created some lists on my Sharepoint.
Next,
I'm trying to get data from Sharepoint with Java :

```
...
ListsSoap listsSoap = new Lists().getListsSoap();
GetListCollectionResult getListCollectionResult = listsSoap.getListCollection();
System.out.println(getListCollectionResult.getContent().toString());
...
```

I have no problem for me authenticate but my result is always a empty list :

```
[[Lists: null]]
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, we have to get the dom response like this :

```
GetListCollectionResult getListCollectionResult = listSoap.getListCollection();
Object result = getListCollectionResult.getContent().get(0);

if(result != null && result instanceof ElementNSImpl)
{
    Document document = ((ElementNSImpl)result).getOwnerDocument();
    System.out.println(WebServiceUtils.xml(document));
}
```

xml is a method which returns the xml string representation of my dom.
Finally, I can see my collection of lists :

```
<Lists xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <List AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" ...
    <List AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" ...
    ...
```

Each List node represents a list in my Sharepoint.
Now, simply browse nodes :

```
NodeList list = ((ElementNSImpl)result).getElementsByTagName("List");
...
```

I hope this will help you.